# How can pass data and put in table dynamic in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I pass data to another view and display or put in dynamic table?

If I have action like this:

```
- (IBAction)steeperchange:(id)sender {
    Quintity1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", x.value];
    res1 = x.value * suop;
    Cost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", res1 + res2];
    suop_q1 = Quintity1.text.intValue;
    Soup_total = res1 + res2;

    //to save data btween view 
    NSString *Quit1value = Quintity1.text;
    NSString *costvalue = Cost.text;

    // Store the data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:Quit1value forKey:@"Quit1value"];
    [defaults setObject:costvalue forKey:@"costvalue"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

If I click  this steeper I want save the (`Quintity1.text.intValue` and price and name of mil) all of this is defined to global variable.

I want move to final view if it click only. I have many steeper changes.

The project like menu of restaurant;
I want to final view print the all cheesed. 
How can make this >>> Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to pass the data you want using a public property in the receiving view controller.  Without seeing more code (the receiving VC's code) and knowing how you are transitioning (storyboard or nibs), it will be hard to help you more.

Comment: thanx EIJay ...  i make the data public  property but i don't have any ida to pass the array of string to final View                             this part of my project can help me  ......   http://www.mediafire.com/?7lgexsn9ilgman3